# Python: execution order in Threading

Tags: python, multithreading

This is a code for testing `Threading`:

```
import threading
import time


episode = 0
lock = threading.Lock()

class Agent(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, id):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.id = id

    def run(self):
        global episode
        while episode < 5:
            with lock:
                print(
                    "{} : episode will be changed {} -> {}".format(
                        self.id,
                        episode,
                        episode+1
                    )
                )
                episode += 1
                print("{} : changed value -> {}".format(self.id, episode))
                time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    agents = []
    for i in range(3):
        agents.append(Agent(i))

    for agent in agents:
        agent.start()
```

Result:

```
0 : episode will be changed 0 -> 1
0 : changed value -> 1
0 : episode will be changed 1 -> 2
0 : changed value -> 2
0 : episode will be changed 2 -> 3
0 : changed value -> 3
0 : episode will be changed 3 -> 4
0 : changed value -> 4
0 : episode will be changed 4 -> 5
0 : changed value -> 5
1 : episode will be changed 5 -> 6
1 : changed value -> 6
2 : episode will be changed 6 -> 7
2 : changed value -> 7
```

This is one of result that I had expected:

```
0 : episode will be changed 0 -> 1
0 : changed value -> 1
2 : episode will be changed 1 -> 2
2 : changed value -> 2
1 : episode will be changed 2 -> 3
1 : changed value -> 3
2 : episode will be changed 3 -> 4
2 : changed value -> 4
0 : episode will be changed 4 -> 5
0 : changed value -> 5
  .
  .
```

I can not understand why thread id=0 keep appearing consecutively in the first place... As I know of, the execution order of threads is random, right?

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread 0 starts first, grabs the lock, and sleeps *while* holding the lock.  There is a very short period of time between the sleep ending, the lock getting released as a result of exiting the `with` block, and the loop acquiring the lock again, so chances are excellent that thread 0 will get the lock again ... and again, and again, until `episode < 5` is finally false.

Remove a level of indentation on your `time.sleep(1)` so it executes as part of the loop instead of as part of the `with` block.  Then thread 0 will release the lock *before* starting its sleep, and other threads are almost certain to get the lock while thread 0 is sleeping (they have a whole second to do so then, instead of far less than an eyeblink).

Answer (score 1):

You are just unlucky? I have tested your code without changing anything and got the following output:

```
0 : episode will be changed 0 -> 1
0 : changed value -> 1
1 : episode will be changed 1 -> 2
1 : changed value -> 2
2 : episode will be changed 2 -> 3
2 : changed value -> 3
2 : episode will be changed 3 -> 4
2 : changed value -> 4
2 : episode will be changed 4 -> 5
2 : changed value -> 5
0 : episode will be changed 5 -> 6
0 : changed value -> 6
1 : episode will be changed 6 -> 7
1 : changed value -> 7
```

Comment: I don't think this should be an answer

Comment: @Unni So what do you expect?

Comment: I feel that it should be a comment saying that you get the a different output when you execute it. I don't see this answer contributing any knowledge. At least an explanation along with the output is still a valuable contribution.

Comment: @Unni If I can use comment to show these output, I will. Or do you think just saying "I get a different output" is enough to make OP understand? Further, I don't think you understand the key point. Threads concurrency is *unexpectable*, so one standalone output cannot represent anything. This is the key point I want to show. So I did post that I use __the same code__ to generate this __different__ output.